# systemctl - service exit codes and status information explanation

Tags: systemd

When checking a service status via `systemctl`

```
systemctl status docker
```

the output is something like

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
  Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-03-19 13:52:21 CST; 4min 32s ago
  Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 6001 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// (code=exited, status=205/LIMITS)
  Main PID: 6001 (code=exited, status=205/LIMITS)
```

The question is about the part in bold: the main process exit code and status information.
Is there a list of all the codes and statuses along with their explanation ?

---

<sup>I know that most times it's self-explanatory (and I know the answer to the question here) but lately we get this question a lot at work (some people search via google but can't find it, other people open the *systemd.service* man page, search for e.g. code *203* and don't find it...) so I thought I might as well put it here so it's easier for people to find the answer via google.</sup>

Comment: Good idea!........

Comment: Read this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410603/script-handling-systemd-services-return-code

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, but only since 2017 when Jan Synacek finally documented them in the systemd manual.  Your work colleagues are simply reading the wrong page of the manual.  ☺

## Further reading

- Lennart Poettering (2017).  "[Process exit codes: systemd-specific exit codes](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#Process%20Exit%20Codes)".  *systemd.exec*.  systemd manual pages.  Freedesktop.org.
- Jan Synacek (2016-06-15) *[Document service status codes](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/3545)*. systemd bug #3545.  GitHub.

Comment: This is helpful. I just like to add that `systemctl` is exiting with code `3` under certain conditions, even if the call was successful and there was no failure. See [Bug 77507](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=77507) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the list of status codes for systemctl

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#Exit%20status