# systemd "status=203/EXEC" error when creating new service

Tags: systemd, python, services

I've created a new service for a Python script that works when running standalone but gives errors below when run through systemd :

```
Oct 02 12:17:09 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Read pressure And Post to mqtt.
Oct 02 12:17:09 raspberrypi systemd[1]: ReadPressure.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Oct 02 12:17:09 raspberrypi systemd[1]: ReadPressure.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 02 12:17:09 raspberrypi systemd[1]: ReadPressure.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 02 12:17:09 raspberrypi systemd[1]: ReadPressure.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Oct 02 12:17:09 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped Read pressure And Post to mqtt.
Oct 02 12:17:09 raspberrypi systemd[1]: ReadPressure.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Oct 02 12:17:09 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start Read pressure And Post to mqtt.
Oct 02 12:17:09 raspberrypi systemd[1]: ReadPressure.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 02 12:17:09 raspberrypi systemd[1]: ReadPressure.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

The service was created in "etc/systemd/system/ReadPressure.service.  it has executable rights.

The services looks like :

```
[Unit]
Description=ReadPressure

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'python3 -u /home/pi/ReadPressure/ReadPressure2AndPostToMqtt.py'
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/ReadPressure/
Restart=always
User=pi

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Any ideas why im getting the errors?   The operating system is Raspbian.

Thanks

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/458648/ .

Comment: Why are you starting a bash that is calling python? You can start python directly with `ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3...` or wherever your python3 binary resides.

Comment: Tried starting directly too.  I saw a example like that so i tried it to see if it gives me different results.

Comment: according to hte docmentation "203 EXIT_EXEC"  says "The actual process execution failed (specifically, the execve(2) system call). Most likely this is caused by a missing or non-accessible executable file."   I guess it cant find the python file?   in the log it says " Started Read pressure And Post to mqtt" but the file is named "ReadPressure2AndPostToMqtt.py".  Do you think that could be part of the problem? i dont know how to correct it, any ideas?

Comment: What does `type python3` return?

Comment: Can you execute the file as the user pi? To verify that, try `su pi` and then just try your command: `/usr/bin/python3 -u /home/pi/ReadPressure/ReadPressure2AndPostToMqtt.py`. Don't forget to `exit` or you'll remain in that environment, which may cause confusion. Also, make sure to also use absolute paths to the executeables.

Comment: "type python3" returns "python3 is /usr/bin/python3"

Comment: ran "su pi" and "/usr/bin/python3 -u /home/pi/ReadPressure/ReadPressure2AndPostToMqtt.py" works fine.

Comment: Please see the FAQ about why things work differently under systemd: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/339645/20239

Comment: Got it working. it was the log file name, change it from "ReadPressure2AndPostToMqtt.py" to "ReadPressure2".

Comment: @resolver101 what does it mean the "log file name"? what log?

Comment: Related Answers: [Systemd Service Failing with exit-code status=203/EXEC](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/664811/systemd-service-failing-with-exit-code-status-203-exec)

Answer (score 49):

Try:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ systemctl status ReadPressure.service
```

Paraphrasing @Ingo from [I fail to start a python program in Thonny on startup](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/92169/i-fail-to-start-a-python-program-in-thonny-on-startup)

The error message (code=exited, status=203/EXEC) is often seen when the script itself or its interpreter cannot be executed.

It could have these reasons:

- wrong path to script (e.g. /home/py/ReadPressure2AndPostToMqtt.py)
- script not executable
- no shebang (first line)
- wrong path in shebang (e.g. /bin/python3)
- internal files in your script might be missing access permissions.
- SELinux may be preventing execution of the ExecStart parameter; check /var/log/audit/audit.log for messages of the form: `type=AVC msg=audit([...]): avc:  denied  { execute }` or in the output of `ausearch -ts recent -m avc -i`.
- You have the wrong `WorkingDirectory` parameter

Comment: Had the same issue as the OP and indeed, forgot the shebang stuff in my script...

Comment: To add to the point "script not executable" - when uploading file from Windows (FTP, `scp`...), make sure that the source file has `LF` (instead of Windows default `CRLF`) line separators.

Comment: no shebang (first line) was the problem, Thanks

Answer (score 15):

Another possible reason for `status=203/EXEC` might be SELinux.
In my case I had a unit file that launched a python script:

```
[Unit]
Description=LibreNMS SNMP Poller Service
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/librenms/librenms-service.py -v -d
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
WorkingDirectory=/opt/librenms
User=librenms
Group=librenms
RestartSec=10
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The python script had SELinux type descriptor `httpd_sys_content_t`, which was not allowed to be executed.
I saw the error by using `audit2why < /var/log/audit/audit.log` which looked like

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1631272189.992:1032): avc:  denied  { execute } for  pid=2873 comm="(rvice.py)" name="librenms-service.py" dev="sda3" ino=714393 scontext=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

        Was caused by:
                Missing type enforcement (TE) allow rule.

                You can use audit2allow to generate a loadable module to allow this access.
```

I ended up editing the Security context.

Non permanent edit (for testing):

```
chcon -t bin_t /opt/librenms/librenms-service.py
```

Permanent edit:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t bin_t '/opt/librenms/librenms-service.py'
restorecon -Fv /opt/bin/librenms-service.py
```

Comment: "chcon -t bin_t" did it for me. Is there any reason you call it a "non-permanent" solution?

Comment: `chcon` will label the file until a relabeling will occur (upgrades). The permanent solution is using `semanage` and then relabel manually with `restorecon`

Comment: I assume that "relabeling" is not something that happens for user-created services, by default?

Comment: Since there are default lables for every default directory, files in /opt will inherit from default /opt label. So your user created service will be relabeled on upgrades.

Answer (score 7):

You may need to quote your command, e.g.:

```
ExecStart="/bin/bash -c 'python3 bla blah'"
```

Comment: thank you, this solved my problem with jupyter [in a conda environment]

Answer (score 3):

In my case I got the following error:
`... /usr/bin/env: 'python3\r': No such file or directory`
based on the shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Took me some time to notice the Carriage return `'\r'`. After deleting it everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the issue was actually a previous service of the same name I had tried to install earlier. I could tell that that was the issue by the references to the old service in the log. Removing the old service and running 'systemctl daemon-reload' fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the bash script to start was on a different physical drive than the one in which the system resides.

Putting the script under `/usr/local/bin` fixed the issue, although I'm not sure why.

Comment: you system can prevent execution of system service from some directories https://serverfault.com/questions/957084/failed-at-step-exec-spawning-permission-denied

Answer (score 0):

I had the error when the binary belong to a root user with permission 700 e.g. hadn't execution permission for others. The service unit use own user so it can't start the service.
I made `chown o+x /sbin/my_service` and it worked after this.
Just wondered that nothing meaningful was written to logs I had to guess.
Maybe systemd needs for some debug flag, if anyone know please let me know.