# How to resolve ""Active: Failed code=exited; status=203/EXEC" error while starting the service in centos

Tags: centos, python, services, uwsgi

I am trying to create a system service for my flask application. This is my service application

`comission_project.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to server comission project
Requires = network.target
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/schirag/comission_project/venv/bin/python3" "/home/schirag/Desktop/comission_project/Hello.py
WorkingDirectory=/home/schirag/Desktop/comission_project
User=schirag
Environment="PATH=/home/schirag/Desktop/comission_project/venv"


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After starting and enabling  the service, I am getting the following status:

```
comission_project.service - uWSGI instance to server comission project
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/comission_project.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2021-08-13 12:50:18 IST; 30min ago
 Main PID: 22192 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Aug 13 12:50:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started uWSGI instance to server comission project.
Aug 13 12:50:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: comission_project.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Aug 13 12:50:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: comission_project.service: Failed with result 'exit-code
```

This is the status when I entered the command - `journalctl -u comission_project`

```
Aug 13 12:50:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started uWSGI instance to server comission project.
Aug 13 12:50:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: comission_project.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Aug 13 12:50:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: comission_project.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

What has to be done to start the service

Comment: Does this answer your question? [systemd "status=203/EXEC" error when creating new service](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/472950/systemd-status-203-exec-error-when-creating-new-service)

Comment: I have edited my `ExecStart` and now my `status:203` is gone, and the code is getting executed. But I am using a virtual environment and have provided `Environment` with the path `/home/schirag/Deskop/comission_project/venv/bin`, but it is giving a module error in the status of the service

Comment: Installing the packages globally solved the error. Need to figure out how to do it using environment. Thank you