# Getting the exit code of a failed systemd service

Tags: linux, systemd, exit-status

How to get the exit-code of a failed systemd service ?

`service some_service status` prints the following :

```
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code)
```

But what is that `exit-code` ?

And are those exit-codes standard or do they have different meanings for different services?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`systemctl status` does have what you're looking for:

```
$ systemctl status openproject-web-1.service
● openproject-web-1.service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/openproject-web-1.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-05-25 08:17:17 CEST; 1 day 4h ago
  Process: 969 ExecStart=/usr/bin/openproject run web (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 969 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
```

You see here under `Main PID:` you have `(code=exited, status=203/EXEC)`.  That 203 is the exit code.

The exit codes are up to the specific application, but there are conventions.  0 is successful exit, 1-255 is abnormal exit, 256+ is out of range.  The [posix standard](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html) has a few special cases.  But you'll want to look at the documentation of the application for anything more than that.

For example, [`grep(1)`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html) says:

> ...the  exit  status is 0 if a line is selected, 1 if no lines were selected, and 2 if an error occurred

As JdePB describes below, systemd may set some exit codes itself in the range of 200 to 242.  In the example above we have exit code `203` which means the actual execution failed (maybe the file was not found or was not marked as executable).

Comment: Read https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/458655/5132 first, especially in this case.